# Rails - New & edit not working with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm working through [this Epicodus lesson](http://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/lessons/magic-methods)  and I just refactored my form partial for the new and edit views, but the new & edit actions are not working. When submitting the update, I'm getting the "name can't be blank" error.

Here's my new, create, edit & update actions in my contacts_controller:

```
def new
  @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
  @contact = Contact.new name: params[:name],
                          email: params[:email],
                            phone: params[:phone]
  if @contact.save
    flash[:notice] = "#{@contact.name} added."
    redirect_to contacts_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  if @contact.update name: params[:name],
                      email: params[:email],
                        phone: params[:phone]
    flash[:notice] = 'Contact updated.'
    redirect_to contact_path(@contact)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

My edit view:

```
<% content_for(:title, "Edit #{@contact.name} | Wikipages") %>

<h1>Edit <%= @contact.name %></h1>

<%= render 'errors'%>
<%= render 'form'%>

<p><%= link_to 'Return to contacts', '/contacts' %></p>
```

My new view:

```
<% content_for(:title, "New contact | Wikipages") %>

<h1>New contact</h1>

<%= render 'errors'%>
<%= render 'form'%>

<p><%= link_to 'Return to contacts', '/contacts', class: 'btn btn-default' %></p>
```

My form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit(class: "btn btn-primary")%>
<% end %>
```

And my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'contacts#index'

  resources :contacts do
    resources :phones
  end
end
```

Here's the output from my log for the new:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-23 07:00:34 -0400
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"q59xzpBWXEs58qStmPcnpEqm89finUQKiUvYsjRYm8Q=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Lance", "phone"=>"", "email"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
   (2.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered contacts/_errors.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered contacts/_form.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 214ms (Views: 207.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

Here's the output from my log for the edit:

```
Started PATCH "/contacts/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-23 06:48:02 -0400
Processing by ContactsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"q59xzpBWXEs58qStmPcnpEqm89finUQKiUvYsjRYm8Q=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Chuck Wight", "phone"=>"435345345e", "email"=>"desfwrf@er.com"}, "commit"=>"Update Contact", "id"=>"12"}
  Contact Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts"  WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered contacts/_errors.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered contacts/_form.html.erb (4.4ms)
  Rendered contacts/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (7.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 208ms (Views: 201.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that the POST/PUT request or you are making GET request only. Please check that.

Comment: For the create action, it's a POST. For the update, it's a PATCH

Comment: for update it should be PUT not PATCH, check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your params nested under contact and you are passing params to your create and update action directly. So try `paarams[:contact][:email]` instead of `params[:email]`

Like this :

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new name: params[:contact][:name],
                          email: params[:contact][:email],
                            phone: params[:contact][:phone]
  if @contact.save
    flash[:notice] = "#{@contact.name} added."
    redirect_to contacts_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end


def update
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  if @contact.update name: params[:contact][:name],
                      email: params[:contact][:email],
                        phone: params[:contact][:phone]
    flash[:notice] = 'Contact updated.'
    redirect_to contact_path(@contact)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Clearly in your update action your are getting `@contact` as nil. So try make changes I suggested in your controller action. Hope this help you.

Comment: 'Couldn't find Contact without an ID' after the change

Comment: thats cool and you can to avoid this much code `@contact.update!(contact_params)`, `def contact_params
                   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :phone)
    end` this should update all the fields. Hope this works

Comment: Mistakenly I have added `@contact = Contact.find(params[;contact][:id])` instead of `@contact = Contact.find(params[:id])` in update action try now this will work. I also updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Are you using rails 4 ?

Comment: if yes than go through http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html